# Chart modify() gives error Exception: Those columns are out of bounds

Tags: google-apps-script

I started re-using a script attached to a spreadsheet that I made a few years ago. If I remember right, it was working fine but it now throws the error: **Exception: Those columns are out of bounds**. The script changes the several options on each chart that was saved to their own page. I can't see how if it's saved to it's own page it has columns. I tried **.setPosition()** which locked up the charts so that  they can't load. I found that under embedded charts and I'm not sure if a chart that is given its own sheet  is considered embedded. My code is below if anyone can help.

[Here is a copy of the sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-uB684YjCwVYn9svr4A1wnFrAW9RpF1Vla68SSMqBhw/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks
Jamie

```
function GM3_modifyAllCharts() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var sheets2 = ss.getSheets();
 for (i = 2; i < (sheets2.length - 6); i++) {
    var shtLabel= ss.getSheetByName("Graph Labels");
    var range = shtLabel.getRange((i-1),1);
    Logger.log(range.getValues());
    var bayValues = range.getValues();
    var range = shtLabel.getRange((i-1),2);
    Logger.log(range.getValues());
    var cropValues = range.getValues();
    var shtData= ss.getSheetByName("GM Data");
    var range = shtData.getRange(1,2);
   Logger.log(range.getValues());
    var dateValues = range.getValues();
    var formattedDate1 = " 1 "; //Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateValues), "GMT+4", "M-d-yy");
    var formattedDate2 = " 2 "; //Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateValues), "GMT+4", "D");
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[i]);
    var chart = sheet2.getCharts()[0];
    Logger.log(sheet2.getName()); 

    chart = chart.modify()
   .setOption('titleTextStyle', {color: '#273746  ', fontSize: 14})
    .setOption('title', 'Sw '+ (i-1)+'   '+ bayValues + '   '+ cropValues)
    .setOption('subtitleTextStyle', {color: '#273746  ', fontSize: 14})
    .setOption('subtitle','Date: '+ formattedDate1+'   Julian: '+ formattedDate2)
    .build();

    sheet2.updateChart(chart); // <<<< Here is where the error happens.
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jason, The problem seems to be using the chart option from the upper right corner to move to it's own sheet. I don't think the sheet is seen as a spreadsheet any more but only a chart hence the columns error. If I create a chart in the GM Data sheet I can change the title but if moved to it own page it throws the column out of bounds error. I know this was working a couple years ago so I guess Google changed somthing and broke it. Still, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

It seems that the sheets containing the charts are of OBJECT type which means we have limited access to editing it to the way you want it. I also tried and replicated how you do it on your end and it resulted to the same error/issue.

### Suggestions

I tried moving/copying your charts to another sheet and it seems that I can freely and easily edit it on the new sheet. What I can suggest is to move your charts to another sheet(new or existing) and use it when modifying your charts moving forward.

Comment: Thanks @Jason I'll try moving everything to a new sheet.

Comment: You're welcome @doralogger. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers